# XML schema issue: Repeating Element not repeating

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a pretty standard xml schema defining an element called "part" that should repeat.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="part">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="part_number" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

problem is, when I use this schema to export a price list I get this:

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<part>
<part_number>10-000</part_number>
<price>151.8</price>
</part>
```

When I want mulitple `<part>` elements.
Where am I messing up in the schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <xs:element name="parts">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="part" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="part_number" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp

Answer (score 2):

Your element needs maxOccurs="unbounded" since the default for maxOccurs is 1.

```
<xs:element name="part" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```